# rem polyfill not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, polyfills

I'm midway through creating my own starter framework.  **[Link here](http://starter.gydev.com/)**

First, excuse the enourmous list of CDN plugins.  Right now I'm just working on writing some custom css overrides for commonly used scripts so they're a little easier to style for different projects.

The issue I've run into is getting REM support in ie8.  I know it's not supported, so i'm trying to use **[this polyfill](https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill)**.   Doesn't seem to want to work.

Here's my ie conditional stack:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/library/css/ie-old.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/library/polyfills/rem.js"></script>    
<![endif]-->    

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-placeholder/2.0.8/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input,textarea').placeholder();
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

The conditional is loading things since respond.js is doing its job to enable media queries, rem just does absolutely nothing.

Anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

ended up being a conflict with typekit, in case it helps anyone else

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue except it was the Google Font API. Basically the REM Polyfill was trying to fix things in the Google CSS file, falling over and then not fixing the following stylesheets. Adding **data-norem** onto the  fixed my issue.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-norem>
```